# Draw rectangle in circle with remains colored in different colours

Tags: vb.net

I need to draw a circle in which I must place a square with corners touching circle line.

After that, four part that remains must be colored with different colors.

Colors of square is not important.

Comment: Is the radius of the circle known?

Comment: yes, it is a 2cm, but can be any value

Comment: Right. So, all you have to do is dissect the circle vertically and horizontally.  Then, each point that the intersecting lines touch the circle gets connected  to the next line.  Basically, just draw a cross through the center of the circle, then connect the points. That will give you the square.  Then just color the square differently.

Comment: Problem is not to draw a square, problem is in coloring remaining parts of circle after drawing square. and each part must be in different color

Comment: Or, if you take the location (x,y) center of the circle and add the radius in each direction on the x, y axis, these will be the 4points of the square.

Comment: How do you mean, can't you just color the circle one color, draw the square, then color the square a different color?  That will give the same effect.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/55aa1t17(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: What did you do so far? please post your code.

Comment: Yeah, just follow the link Justin Ryan made above and use the Drawing Filled Shapes.  Draw a filled circle, then draw the filled square inside of it with a different color.

Comment: When you draw a square in circle, then this figure forms remaining four parts of circle beside a square. all that four parts need to be in different color, red, green, blue and white.

Comment: Here's how i'd do that: create 4 rectangle panels that overlap all at one point so it looks like a cross. the middle part were they all overlap will be were you draw your square later. now draw a circle in every of these panels. the middle of the circle  will be the middle of the overlapping point. make sure the circle is bigger than your overlapping point. so the part of your circle you wanna see will be outside the overlapping part and the other 3 parts will be "outside" of the panel. therefor invisible. last draw your square on the top panel.

Comment: @Index Have you code for this solution to try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this out:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
        Dim radius As Integer = 100
        Dim center As New Point(125, 125)
        Dim Y As Integer = radius * Math.Sin(45 * Math.PI / 180)
        Dim X As Integer = radius * Math.Cos(45 * Math.PI / 180)
        Dim centerRC As New Rectangle(center.X - X, center.Y - Y, X * 2, Y * 2)
        Dim ellipseRC As New Rectangle(center.X - radius, center.Y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2)

        e.Graphics.ExcludeClip(centerRC)
        e.Graphics.FillPie(Brushes.Red, ellipseRC, 225, 90)
        e.Graphics.FillPie(Brushes.Green, ellipseRC, -45, 90)
        e.Graphics.FillPie(Brushes.Blue, ellipseRC, 45, 90)
        e.Graphics.FillPie(Brushes.White, ellipseRC, 135, 90)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Result:

[image: Ellipse Problem Output]